# Frame created in another frame in chrome

Tags: html, xhtml

```
<html>
   <frameset rows="50%,50%">
      <frame src="three.html"/>
      <frameset cols ="50%,50%">
         <frame src="one.html" />
         <frame src="two.html" />
      </frameset>
   </frameset>
</html>
```

On IE, Firefox I can see only three frames i.e one frame in first  row and two frames in second row
But in chrome I see three frames and again the three frames are created in second frame.

Can someone please explain why there is a change in chrome and how to overcome it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Itay — Really? When it involves **multiple** HTML documents? JSFiddle?!

Comment: @Itay — What makes you think that?

Comment: I don't understand what you people are discussing and talking about.

Comment: @Krishna — Itay is suggesting that a live demo would be helpful. I'm suggestion that the place he thinks it should go would not be useful.

Comment: A live demo would be useful, but the question should include enough information for people to reproduce the problem. [I can't](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/19022463/), Chrome only renders three frames for me.

Comment: @Quentin Yep Quentin you're right. I didn't notice that the OP says the problem is **inside** one of the frames.

Comment: which chrome version are you using?

Comment: My experience matches Quentin's (i.e. no differences) and I've tested with Chromium 28.0.1500.71 on Linux (64 bit) and Chromium 31.0.1630.0 (223066) on Windows (32 bit).